# Как убрать отображение ссылки

Tags: html, css

нигде не могу найти информацию как это убрать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

она показывается при наводе на ссылку, но мне нужно чтобы её не было видно

```html
<center><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"><img class="imgag" src="Images/jpg/zastavka.jpg" alt="content"></a></center>
```

вот код картинки - кнопки

Comment: Никак не убрать.

Comment: Можете добавлять ссылки через `onclick`, но это не есть хорошо.

Comment: вам не обязательно использовать href, да и без ссылки можно обойтись. на любом контроле пишете onclick="window.location.href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'" и он становится кликабельным. так принято, что браузер показывает поле href у ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю код, который добавляет событие "click" к элементу с id "link" и когда пользователь кликает на этот элемент, выполняется функция, переданная в addEventListener.

Функция внутри addEventListener использует [Location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) для загрузки и отображения нового документа по указанному URL.

```js
document.querySelector('#link').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.location.assign('https://example.com/');
});
```

```css
.paragraph-link {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

.paragraph-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p id="link" class="paragraph-link">
  Перейти на сайт example.com
</p>
```